# Animated Section Indicator using <ul> like twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap and has a very long page that I divide into multiple sections.

I'd like to implement a Section Indicator on top left of the screen that always shows where the reader is currently reading, like the screenshot below:

[image: Section Indicator - final, working example can be seen from global.tommy.com]

I managed to get the layout correctly as shown here:

[image: My working version]

However, I've got some problems that I've been working for a few weeks but still can't solved:

1. How to mark the current section dynamically as the user scroll
2. How to animate the movement of the arrow from the source to the next

   (or directly to the destination if the reader click a farther away

   rather than scrolling)

I've tried with the simpler version from getbootstrap.com/components but still to no avail... Please help... this is very stressful as I'm particularly weak in javascript and css :(

[image: the <ul> <li> in getbootstrap.com/components works too, but it is not included in the component and I also cant figure out the code for that :(]

EDIT:

To summarize the answer:

Take a look at this library:

https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav.git

Comment: if you have a try this? please share your html and css source code in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a single-page website have a look at the One Page Navigation Plugin http://trevordavis.net/blog/jquery-one-page-navigation-plugin. It assigns a css-class to the current menu item upon clicking and as the user scrolls down the page.

Comment: Thanks! The library is easy to understand and easy to extend even though I'm not good in js and css!